# $literal usage in Golang-mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I can't understand how to properly use $literal. I am using mgo.v2 and mgo.v2/bson package.

```
db.store.aggregate([
{"$project":{
    "location":{
        "type":{"$literal":"Point"},
        "coordinates":["$longitude","$latitude"]
    }}
},])
```

I used the above code to fetch data in mongodb and working fine.It gives me the result

```
 { "location":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[77.587073,12.958794] 
        }}
```

I tried to use the same in golang and it is shown below

```
pipe :=DB.C("store").Pipe([]bson.M{
        {"$project":bson.M{"location":
        bson.M{"type":
         bson.M{"$literal":"Point"},"coordinates":[]interface{}{"$longitude","$latitude"}}}}}
```

Above code, throws me an error

> panic: bad query: BadValue: Point must be an array or object

so I replaced it  like this

```
pipe :=DB.C("store").Pipe([]bson.M{
        {"$project":bson.M{"location":
        bson.M{"$literal":
         bson.M{"type":"Point"},"coordinates":[]interface{}{"$longitude","$latitude"}}}}})
```

but this also throws me an error

> panic: this object is already an operator expression, and can't be
>   used as a document expression (at 'coordinates')

my complete work is shown in the below link
[my work is here](https://play.golang.org/p/2DcDUJhm6k)
please help me to solve this. 
Thank you

Comment: Can you show more of your code, because your first version works for me?

Comment: I added my work as you asked. I am having a problem in converting the code from MongoDB query to Golang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be complete, this is what you actually try to do:

```
pipe := DB.C("store").Pipe([]bson.M{
    {"$project": bson.M{"location": bson.M{"type": bson.M{"$literal": "Point"}, "coordinates": []interface{}{"$longitude", "$latitude"}}}},
    {"$match": bson.M{"location": bson.M{"$geoWithin": bson.M{"$centerSphere": []interface{}{"$coordinates", 10 / 6378.11}}}}},
})
```

The problem is not with your `"Point"` literal, it's just a mere coincidence. If you change it to `"Pt"` for example, you will still see the exact same error message.

The `Point` in the error message refers to [`$centerSphere`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/#op._S_centerSphere), which expects a center *point* and a radius. And the way you try to "pass" it does not work.

This works for example:

```
"$centerSphere": []interface{}{[]interface{}{1.0, 2.0}, 10 / 6378.11}
```

Your original query does not make sense, as you try to find documents where the location is within 10 kilometers from *itself*, which would match all documents.

Instead you want to / should query documents which are within 10 kilometers of a *specific* location, and you may pass the coordinates of this specific location to `$centerSphere`:

```
myLong, myLat := 10.0, 20.0

// ...

"$centerSphere": []interface{}{[]interface{}{myLong, myLat}, 10 / 6378.11}
```

The complete query:

```
myLong, myLat := 10.0, 20.0
pipe := DB.C("store").Pipe([]bson.M{
    {"$project": bson.M{"location": bson.M{"type": bson.M{"$literal": "Point"}, "coordinates": []interface{}{"$longitude", "$latitude"}}}},
    {"$match": bson.M{"location.coordinates": bson.M{"$geoWithin": bson.M{"$centerSphere": []interface{}{[]interface{}{myLong, myLat}, 10 / 6378.11}}}}},
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It is working fine. Thanks for clarifying about "Point" which refers to centre sphere. I can see that you changed  "location"  to  "location.coordinates" where I used as $coordinates which is entirely wrong.

Comment: "location" or "location.coordinates" work fine. I didn't find any diffrence in them but the problem is "$coordinates" which i should use lat and long. Thanks.

Comment: @hariprasad Yes, I've tested and both works fine, but I felt it's more appropriate to specify `"location.coordinates"`.