# How to write query $centerSphere using mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have read the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/#unsorted-with-geowithin) talks about writing query to get some location within the radius:

```
db.restaurants.find({ location:
   { $geoWithin:
      { $centerSphere: [ [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ], 5 / 3963.2 ] } } })
```

Now I try to write it using `mgo` driver but I don't get the idea how to write it here what I have tried :

```
var cites []City

collection := mongo.DB("Db").C("Collection")

err = collection.Find(bson.M{
    "location": bson.M{
        "$geoWithin": bson.M{
            "$centerSphere" : [ [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ], 5 / 3963.2 ],
        },
    },
}).All(&cites)
```

Yes above code absolutely not working becuase I don't know how to translate this `[ [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ], 5 / 3963.2 ]` in go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [`$centerSphere`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/#op._S_centerSphere) you have to pass a center point and a radius in a slice of type `[]interface{}`, where the point is also a slice containing its coordinates, can also be of type `[]interface{}`.

```
err = collection.Find(bson.M{
    "location": bson.M{
        "$geoWithin": bson.M{
            "$centerSphere": []interface{}{
                []interface{}{-73.93414657, 40.82302903}, 5 / 3963.2,
            },
        },
    },
}).All(&cites)
```

See a related / possible duplicate question:

[$literal usage in Golang-mgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619702/literal-usage-in-golang-mgo/42624044#42624044)